# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.' microsoft visual studio 2022 with database access

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2022

please help me. i have new problem with my code in visual studio 2022.

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb
 Public Class LoginForm1

' TODO: Insert code to perform custom authentication using the provided username and password 
' (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=35339).  
' The custom principal can then be attached to the current thread's principal as follows: 
'     My.User.CurrentPrincipal = CustomPrincipal
' where CustomPrincipal is the IPrincipal implementation used to perform authentication. 
' Subsequently, My.User will return identity information encapsulated in the CustomPrincipal object
' such as the username, display name, etc.
Dim sql As String
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tbluseraccounts WHERE userusername = '" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and userpassword = '" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "' "
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    con.Open()

    With cmd
        .Connection = Con
        .CommandText = sql
    End With
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Me.Hide()
        Stock_Master.Show()
        Stock_Master.Focus()
        UsernameTextBox.Clear()
        PasswordTextBox.Clear()
    End If
    Con.Close()
End Sub
```

and with error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has
> not been initialized.'

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection. You can see it for yourself by typing `' or 1=1; --` to the username textbox. See this for additional info and how to prevent it: https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. Specify the connection parameters before opening the connection:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
' <snip> .. empty con.
con.Open()
```

Comment: thanks bro. but i'm still confused about the code completion

Comment: Add your connection parameters to the connection object. As is, you try to open an empty object ...